# Hibernate PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate mapping which was working until recently - and while I'm sure this is the result of some change I've made, I can't seem to find it.

The mapping file defines a field as:

```
<id name="id" column="id">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

The class defines this field as:

```
private Long id;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: 
    IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of MyClass.id
```

The database field to which this corresponds is defined as:

```
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

I have several other classes with similar structures and definitions, and have no issues with them. However, likely resulting from some recent change I made, this one particular mapping will no longer work properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure but you can try this :

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Hibernate may be setting wrong value.