# Execute stored procedure from hibernate fails with PropertyAccessException

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server Database. I am trying to invoke it from java code. I am using hibernate SQLQuery to invoke the procedure. I am able to invoke and get the result properly. However, if I try to map the results to an entity, I am getting Hibernate Exception.

I tried with different types for the id. Tried with  `long`, `Long`, `String`. But everything is giving the same error.

> org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException
>   occurred while calling setter of
>   com.myapp.reports.service.ProcBean.id

Here is how I am invoking the procedure.

```
List list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("{CALL SummaryReport(:ids, :EventDescriptionId, :DateFrom, :DateTo)}")
                .setParameter("ids","155")
                .setParameter("EventDescriptionId","299")
                .setParameter("DateFrom","2014-04-01")
                .setParameter("DateTo", "2014-05-01")
                .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ProcBean.class))
                .list();
```

Entity:

```
public class ProcBean {

    private Long id;
    private Long total;
    private Double average;
    private Long minimum;
    private Long maximum;
    private Long startVal;
    private Long endVal;

//and the setters
}
```

Comment: use jdbctemplate to execute your SP

Comment: @NiravPrajapati : How can I map the resultset to entity?

Comment: @YaduKrishnan what is this VehicleId in ProcBean? Is there any property in the bean

Comment: @ManjunathAnand : Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the question. I copied the previous error message, but the code was changed after that.

Comment: @YaduKrishnan check if this helps:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302663/hibernate-propertyaccessexception-illegalargumentexception

Comment: Finally I was able to make it work using the addScalar() method :)